# How to install Mist 0.8.3 on Windows?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, installation

Last version of Mist I used was 0.8.1 - once unpacked, the directory had everything needed to run both Mist and geth - both of the executables were there. Now when I downloaded the latest Mist 0.8.3 release, the folder only comes with `Ethereum Wallet Setup 0.8.3.exe`, and it doesn't behave like a normal installer - it starts the wallet right away without actually doing any setup, before freezing during peer search.

What is the correct way of installing the newest Mist wallet so I can have access to both the wallet and geth?

Answer (score 1):

no installation is needed because you have a previous Mist.

in the Mist doc, it is indicated that :

> **For updating simply download the new version and copy it over the old one** (keep a backup of the old one if you want to be sure). The
>   data folder for Mist is stored in other places:
>
> Windows %APPDATA%\Mist
>
> macOS ~/Library/Application Support/Mist
>
> Linux ~/.config/Mist

if you delete this folder the installation process will be launched else the new mist will popup without installation.

just be careful, many users signaled some issues with this version :

https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues

Answer (score 1):

Run the setup file with Task Manager open. Right-click the Mist or Geth process and select "open containing folder".

0.8.3 installs in a weird folder... not sure why. Once you find the files, just createyour own shortcuts for them and DO NOT run the "setup" again. I briefly noticed it scrubs the install folder each time and you lose any files you put in there, but I didn't test it twice... just noticed a shortcut I made with geth flags disappeared from the geth folder when I re-ran the setup file.

I just copied my old keystore stuff to the Appdata folder. I also used the MKLINK utility https://superuser.com/a/902082/165822 to point at my ChainData folder on a different drive.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10:
Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization - Show hidden files and folders - Apply - OK

(AppData is usually a hidden folder so you don't mess around with it.)

Then Look for Mist and Ethereum folders under

```
C:\Users\"computername-username"\AppData\Local
```

or

```
C:\Users\"computername-username"\AppData\Roaming
```

Mist App is under Mist folder. Create a shortcut on your desktop. Click Mist app to run it. You don't need to run Mist setup every time.