# How to recover Mist and wallet?

Tags: mist

Yesterday, everything was fine (Mist 0.8.9), today when I started it, all my tokens were gone and there was no transaction history. It told me that there was a new version (0.8.10), which I downloaded and installed. After doing that, everything was gone, wallet, blockchain etc etc, it's like I have to start over from scratch. I tried the old shortcuts and the old application (mist.exe), but it's all gone. What did I do wrong and why isn't there just a simple way to update from within the application? How do I recover my wallet and everything I downloaded? What files does it delete during the installation? Thanks,

Comment: to update mist please read https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/how-to-install-mist-0-8-3-on-windows/8818#8818

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I just reran the executable when I upgraded to 0.8.9, but anyway, how do I recover my original Mist now? Everything is totally messed up and I don't want to lose my tokens..